# Github AutoUpdate with cron

Tags: bash, git, github, cron

I have a cron task that is performed every 5 minutes. It launches a bash script that looks for if a change is made on github and if it does, updates the code. However, no updates are found when there is one and if I run the script manually, it works. Someone to help me? Thanks in advance, OverSquid.

Cron task:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/pi/Documents/palamazon-bot/git-update.sh > /home/pi/Documents/bot-updates/latest.txt
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Documents/palamazon-bot
if [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) = $(git ls-remote $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} | sed 's/\// /g') | cut -f1) ]; then
    echo "No update"
else
    echo "New update"
    git pull > /dev/null 2>&1
    npm i > /dev/null 2>&1
    pm2 restart ./main.js > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Code updated."
fi
```

**Thanks for your help! OverSquid.**

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Quote the compared strings `if [ "$(git ...)" = "..." ]`
- Set `PATH` in the script, then test by running under `env -i ./yourscript`
- Do not throw away stdout and stderr, save them in a file
- Read the mails cron sent you to identify the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it doesn't work....